# Artemis k8s cluster client connection handling

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-artemis, kubernetes-service, artemiscloud

I am using the Artemis Cloud operator for deploying ActiveMQ Artemis in k8s cluster. Number of replicas configured is 3. Queues are expected to be created by client applications. Operator creates a headless service and service for each pod in the cluster setup.

Whenever client connects to a pod ,it creates a queue in that broker pod.So if client connects to 3 brokers at random time, three queues gets created in pods, one in each pod respectively.So when a producer sends message to the queue, it is sent to the connected pod. It wont be present in each broker pod.(No replication of messages).

My question is what service name should client applications use inorder to connect to artemis pods and also maintain session affinity? In other words, what should be done in order to make a client connect to same broker whenever it tries a connection?(and avoid duplicate queue creation)

What I currently use is a kubernetes clusterip service I created that splits traffics to pods.And queues are created via stomp producer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which helm it will be using in the background but you will be using the **service name** inside the **kubernetes** app for connection instead of the **ClusterIP**.

Service name could be starting the with **helm** chart name. i was checking and referring this chart for ref : https://github.com/deviceinsight/activemq-artemis-helm could be different.

Looks like it's creating the service with **Cluster IP**:**none** (**Headless service**) so connecting to the existing service is not working, i doubt currently it might be returning all the **PODs IP**.

**Option : 2 if above one not work give try to this**

In another case, you can create the new service type **clusterIP** with a different name, everything else will be the same, like port and all.

In service you can notice amqp, mqtt and other port, so you app will connect to new service with port config as per requirement. For example : `active-mq-service:61613`

If everything working fine for you and you are just looking for session affinity you can add this config to your service and it will start managing the session affinity.

`SessionAffinity: ClientIP`

> If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are
> passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity
> based on the client's IP addresses by setting
> service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP" (the default is "None").
> You can also set the maximum session sticky time by setting
> service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds
> appropriately. (the default value is 10800, which works out to be 3
> hours).

Ref doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was refereing to operator from https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-operator . The only thing I havent tried from your suggestions is the sessionAffinity setting. In  my scenario,my client app will need to connect to multiple pods actually. ie, I require load balancing for requests.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is some configuration that can be configured from client applications or artemis so that only one queue will be created in total considering 3 broker pods. The issue i am facing is i miss messages because consumer listens to a different pod where as producer sends message to different pod. But both of them are using same k8s service name.

Comment: that's weird ideally it should not work that way, consumer producer both use the same service and port by subscribe or send message to queue and can easily get those.